# Concurrency control algorithm

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I am trying to modify a concurrency control algorithm to take advantage of priority of threads (i.e if lower priority thread and higher priority thread wants to enter critical section at same time, the higher priority thread goes in first, while the lower priority thread waits for certain no. of cycles).

Here is the modified algorithm:

```c
procphase[i] = want_cr;
int j = turn;

do {
    while (j != i) {
        if (procphase[j] != out_cr) 
        {
            if (procphase[j] == want_cr && thrd_prty[i]<thrd_prty[j])
            {
                if(turndown[i]<5)
                {
                    turndown[i]=turndown[i]+1;
                    j=turn;
                }   
            }
            else if(procphase[j] ==claim_cr)
            {
                j=turn;
            }
            else{}
        }
        else j=(j+1)%n;
    }

    procphase[i] = claim_cr;
    j = (j + 1) % n;
    while (procphase[j] != claim_cr) j = (j + 1) % n;

} while (!(j == i && (turn == i || procphase[turn] == out_cr)));

turn = i;
```

The original algorithm is the Eisenberg McGuire algorithm,
but sometimes the algorithm is getting stuck in between and I could not find why.

Comment: How do you know it's getting stuck? What errors or feedbacks are you getting?

Comment: I won't pretend that I quite understand this code, but I do notice that there's at least the potential for the inner `while` loop to get stuck: if the two first `if` conditions are true but the third is false, `j` isn't changed. The fourth `if` has a similar issue.